# Como faço para executar fortran desde o matlab?

Tags: matlab, fortran

Estou precisando executar um arquivo fortran desde o matlab.

1. Qual é o melhor compilador quando utilizo o windows
2. Quais são os passo para criar um arquivo executável.

Agradeço pelo ajuda,

Comment: Olá! o que você quer dizer com "desde o matlab?"